# Need to have to function create a new array instead of pushing data for my React Component

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a method that is using the `.push` method. Which is not creating a new array of data. How can I refactor the following function to accomplish this? Here is my code.

```js
formatDataForBarChart(data) {
    let chartArray = [];
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
      data.map(activity => {
        activity.domains.map((domain) => {
          const chartData =  {
            name: domain.domainName,
            riskScore: domain.riskScore
          }
          chartArray.push(chartData)
      })
    })
  }
  return chartArray;
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure what this question is asking. You are not using map properly though, your probably want to be using foreach.  You should show us an example of what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @Deadron The `chartData` is being pushed into the `chartArray` that is not immutable. I want this to create a new array not push data to it.

Answer (score 0):

The callback of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should return an item, and map would return an array. Nested `Array.map()` calls return an array of array, which you can flatten using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (not supported by Edge/IE):

```
function formatDataForBarChart(data = []) {
  return data.map(activity =>
    activity.domains.map(domain => ({
      name: domain.domainName,
      riskScore: domain.riskScore
    }))
  ).flat();
}
```

If `Array.flat()` is not supported by your target browsers [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to flatten the array of arrays:

```
function formatDataForBarChart(data = []) {
  return [].concat(...data.map(activity =>
    activity.domains.map(domain => ({
      name: domain.domainName,
      riskScore: domain.riskScore
    }))
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be worth it for you to read up about [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

But your code can be refactored to always return a new reference to an array like so

```
function formatDataForBarChart(data) {
  const chartArray = [];

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach(activity => {
      activity.domains.forEach(domain => {
        const chartData = {
          name: domain.domainName,
          riskScore: domain.riskScore
        };
        chartArray.push(chartData);
      });
    });
  }

  return chartArray;
}
```

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
formatDataForBarChart(data) {
let chartArray = [];
if (data && data.length > 0) {
    let chartDataArray=[];
    data.forEach(activity => {
        var reformatData = activity.domains.map((domain) => {
            var chartData = {};
            chartData.name: domain.domainName;
            chartData.riskScore: domain.riskScore;
            return chartData;
        })
        chartDataArray.push(reformatData)
    })
}
```

}